# How to add an attribute with HTML other than adding it to the end of the tag?

Tags: html, angularjs, salesforce, apex

I'm implementing the below code which I got from an [angularjs table sort function](http://mattiash.github.io/angular-tablesort/).

You can see below that ts attributes are being added to the html. However, this isn't an acceptable form to be hosted on Salesforce. Is there another way to add an attribute besides by the method shown below?

```
<table class="table" ts-wrapper>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th ts-criteria="Id">Id</th>
      <th ts-criteria="Name|lowercase" ts-default>Name</th>
      <th ts-criteria="Price|parseFloat">Price</th>
      <th ts-criteria="Quantity|parseInt">Quantity</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="item in items track by item.Id" ts-repeat>
      <td>{{item.Name}}</td>
      <td>{{item.Price | currency}}</td>
      <td>{{item.Quantity}}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

See here for codepen of the code I'm try: http://codepen.io/chriscruz/pen/emzvjo?editors=101

Here is my attempt using some of the suggestions below: http://codepen.io/chriscruz/pen/vEKxVg

Comment: I am not sure about salesforce restriction, is it for html validity? You could try prefixing it with data. `data-ts-repeat` or do `ts-repeat="ts-repeat"`

Comment: @PSL, do you wanna go ahead and submit the revised html with the `data-` prefixes as an answer? I would do it myself, but I don't wanna look like I'm stealing your answer away, :-)

Comment: @Marventus I would do it. But i am really not sure because data prefix might not just work because even angular attributes when used as is are invalid. But possibly as OP said issue is with standalone attributes for which providing a value might work. I 'd wait for OP confirmation if it worked or not.. :)

Comment: @PSL, I just tried and the following code: http://jsfiddle.net/Marventus/g0ppcko7/ validates just fine in the W3C Validator.

Comment: @Marventus Actually you are probably right. I got confused by the question title and the question. SO i posted answer. Thank you for the note. So hopefully might as well work for OP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try prefixing them with [`data-`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes) so they become html5 complaint and angular parses them too. If there is still an issue with standalone attribute example (`data-ts-wrapper`) then probably you could just provide a value for them, example- `data-ts-wrapper="ts-wrapper"` (Since it looks like those directives does no expect any expression anyways as its value).

So try:

```
<table class="table" ts-wrapper="ts-wrapper"> <!-- or try  ts-wrapper="ts-wrapper"--> 
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th ts-criteria="Id">Id</th>
      <th ts-criteria="Name|lowercase" ts-default="ts-default">Name</th>
      <th ts-criteria="Price|parseFloat">Price</th>
      <th ts-criteria="Quantity|parseInt">Quantity</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="item in items track by item.Id" ts-repeat="ts-repeat">
      <td>{{item.Name}}</td>
      <td>{{item.Price | currency}}</td>
      <td>{{item.Quantity}}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I've tried to implement your solution, but I can't seem to get it to work as no data is flowing through. I've added two code pens above with what I'm trying to get to work. Here's my attempt at your code: http://codepen.io/chriscruz/pen/vEKxVg and the original code that was working: http://codepen.io/chriscruz/pen/emzvjo?editors=101

Comment: Do you see any kind of warnings when you run on salesforce. Meaning  do you know specifically which all attributes/html elements get the warning?

Comment: i got your solution to work by just removing 'data-'. I don't understand why that works vs. using 'data-', but it works! Here's the working codepen with your solution: http://codepen.io/chriscruz/pen/PwzpxO

Comment: Wow that is super wierd and something new to me. I have never used salesforce anytime though.. :) I though prefixing data- should always make the html valid... :o